# http://127.0.0.1/home/index.php - Browser could not connect to

Tags: mysql, apache, phpmyadmin, easyphp

I have installed Easyphp12.1 on my Windows 8 booted laptop. When I access localhost i.e., 127.0.0.1:8887, it is working.

However, when I navigate to access phpmyadmin or something else with the URL, `http://127.0.0.1/home/index.php` or  `http://127.0.0.1:8887/home/index.php`, it's not able to connect.

The apache port is listening to `127.0.0.1:8887`

Comment: try `http://localhost/phpmyadmin`

Comment: I tried it.. Not working.

Comment: Oops! Browser could not connect to localhost

Comment: In a Command Prompt, run ‘netstat -ao > netstat.txt’ to write active connections and associated process IDs (PID) to a file (for me, there were too many to just view them in the command prompt)
Find the PID that is listening on port 80 (0.0.0.0:80) – for me, the PID was 4, which seems quite common
Open Task Manager (Ctrl + Shift + Esc), right click on the column headers, and then click PID to show the PID column. Sort by PID to find the process for the PID that you identified above.

Comment: After a bit of searching around, one common solution, and the one that worked for me, was to turn off the “World Wide Web Publishing Service”, as follows:

Go to Control Panel > Administrative Tools > Services
Find ”World Wide Web Publishing Service”
Right click and select “Stop”
Right click and select “Properties”, then change “Startup type” to “Manual”
If this doesn’t fix it, you can find out what is using port 80 as above :

Answer (score -1):

UPDATE Feb 10th, 2014 Venkateshwaran Selvaraj solved the problem:

When I entered this URL directly

http://127.0.0.1:8887/modules/phpmyadmin3522x140127182138/

it takes me to phpmyadmin.